# Extract last block of data in a file using awk

Tags: awk

I have data in the form:

```
0.01 0.02 92 ...
0.02 0.02 11 ...
0.03 0.02 32 ...

0.09 0.02 77 ...
0.01 0.03 88...
0.04 0.01 99 ...

0.02 0.02 34 ...
0.60 0.01 73 ...
0.91 0.08 92 ...
```

How do I (using awk or otherwise) grab just the last block of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'END {print}' RS= output.dat
```

Setting `RS=` makes awk think each block is a line. The `END {print}` part prints the last "line" of the file.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly off-the-wall method using `tac` and `sed`:

```
tac yourfile | sed /^$/q | tac
```

It cats the file backwards and then prints with `sed` till it encounters a blank line and then quits. The file is then reversed back to its original order.

Comment: TIL about tac. Cheers!

Comment: +1: However, I would use `Q` instead of `q`. Difference is `q` prints the current pattern space before quitting if auto-print is not disabled. As a result it will give you an empty line at the begining (in case of your current answer), or you can use `tac file | sed -n '/^$/q;p' | tac`

Comment: @jaypal: +1 Thank you. I was going for the least common denominator as the `sed` on my very recent Mac running OSX Mavericks doesn't accept `Q`.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Or maybe @Hemmer's answer? If so, could you please accept one of the answers so that one of us gets a lovely big green tick? If not, please say what didn't work, so that we, or someone else, can assist you further.